# data garbled while using form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

When i submit a form using `form.submit()`, non-english chars (say chinese, korean) in stored as garbled in database.

I have using the following code in jsp:

```
<%
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
 <body>
 <form name="TestForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<%=formaction%>" method="POST">
  <table>
   <tr><td>Source</td><td>:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="SOURCE"> </td></tr>

   <tr><td>Category</td><td>:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="CATEGORY"> </td></tr>

   <tr><td>Message</td><td>:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="MESSAGE"> </td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ok"></td></tr>
  </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am setting request options like `Content-type`, `CharSet` when i send Ajax request. It's working as expected in Ajax, but even i set those attributes in form, it is not working on `form.submit()`.

Comment: can you give more info about your db? which are you using ? also you need to configure your db as well to use utf-8 as well as form processer

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL with UTF-8 as charSet.

The same data is getting populated when i use ajax. Then there is should be no problem is db configuration right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I have resolved this issue.I have used a custom filter without using **characterEncodingFilter** since this problem occurred. After added this filter and configured in WEB-INF/web.xml, everything is works fine.

For more information refer this wiki:
*http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8*

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching the value on the server side using the following code. Ensure character encoding is set prior to getParameter

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
String str = request.getParameter("fuzz-field");
```

Also check if your server has URIEncoding set to UTF-8

Hope this helps

Here is the sample code that I tried and got it working

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8 %> 

  <form id="form-sample" name="form-sample" method="post" action="/HTML5Sample/sampleservlet">
<!--field has the value of two Chinese characters.-->
<input type="text" id="fuzz-field" name="fuzz-field" value="中文"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Tomcat Server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Servlet class -

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
String str = request.getParameter("fuzz-field");
System.out.println("character field " + str);
```

To view this on eclipse console you will need to modify the console settings - Window > Preference > encoding to utf-8

Comment: Treid the same as you mentioned but no luck. When i get the encoding type using request.getCharacterEncoding() it is coming as "UTF-8". But data is garbled.

Comment: I have pasted sample code, can you verify, which app server are you using ?